# azure search request with scoringParameter query param returns error

Tags: azure, search, scoring-profile

We have a tags field in the search index just like:

```
{
            "name": "tags",
            "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
            "searchable": true,
            "filterable": true,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": false,
            "facetable": true,
            "key": false,
            "indexAnalyzer": null,
            "searchAnalyzer": null,
            "analyzer": null,
            "synonymMaps": []
}
```

and the following tag scoring profile:

```
{
            "name": "tagBoost",
            "functionAggregation": "sum",
            "text": null,
            "functions": [
                {
                    "fieldName": "tags",
                    "interpolation": "linear",
                    "type": "tag",
                    "boost": 15,
                    "freshness": null,
                    "magnitude": null,
                    "distance": null,
                    "tag": {
                        "tagsParameter": "doctype"
                    }
                }
            ]
}
```

When requesting a search just like https://my-beautiful-products-index.search.windows.net/indexes/products/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=karin&scoringParameter=doctype-serial, we get

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Expected 0 parameter(s) but 1 were supplied.\r\nParameter name: scoringParameter"
    }
}
```

Anybody know **why** is this and how to **get rid** of the error?

We've gone through the (scarce) documentation and that request seems to be ok and no traces of that error was found either in docs or Internet :-/.

Even if you keep `scoringParameter` alone (`...&scoringParameter`), the error is the same; it only gets away if we remove the `scoringParameter` from the query string.

Answer (score 3):

I know it not been answered from long, but for others to refer.
Missing part was to add `&scoringProfile="name"`. For me adding this worked.

In this case- https://my-beautiful-products-index.search.windows.net/indexes/products/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=karin&scoringProfile=tagBoost&scoringParameter=doctype-serial,